# How to make 10 post of one category

Tags: categories

How can I make 10 posts of one category. What query should I use.

Here in following query I need its limit of post in per page.

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="content" class="category">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <h1 class="page-title">Category Archives: <span><?php echo  single_cat_title(); ?></span></h1>

            <div class="archive-meta"><?php echo category_description(); ?> </div>
  <div class="post">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <h2 id="post-2451">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            <?php endwhile;?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

I meant to say that I want 10 posts in category.php . Let suppose I am clicking one category in categories so it should show result 10 post of each category.

Comment: Please clean up the code you posted. Also: Please clarify what your question is. Do you want to retrieve 10 post of a category? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You were active an hour ago and still haven't updated your question as @kraftner asked. How do you expect anyone to answer your question. Do you need 10 posts on a `category.php` type template, or 10 posts from a specific category on a `page.php` type template, or just 10 posts generally on a category page

Comment: @PieterGoosen Please be patient. Not updated in an hour... not really a reason to push :)

Comment: LOL, ok @kaiser will use a little more patience :)

Comment: I meant to say that I want 10 posts in category.php . let suppose i am clicking one category in categories so it should show result 10 post of each category. i will appreciate if you can let me know Thnaks

Comment: I am waiting for that but Sorry for late responsed

Comment: You should always make the edits requested directly to your question by clicking on [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/143383/edit) below your question. By doing this, your question will again move to the no1 spot, alerting any one of a change. Also use the `@` symbol if you need to address someone specifically. By just posting a comment you way you did, it never gets directed to anyone, so we don't know if anything was posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and [`is_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) conditional tags to set `posts_per_page` to 10 for category pages.

Here is a working exacmple

```
function wpse_posts_cat_pages( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_posts_cat_pages' );
```

What this code do:

- Check if it is the main query `$query->is_main_query()` and if the page is a category (category.php) page `$query->is_category()`, and if both of these are valid, the amount of posts are limited to 10, no matter what is set in the back end

Comment: Excellent. As my answer solved your problem, would you please credit me by accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer just below the up/down arrows. This will make sure that my answer not only helps you, but others as well.